# 2012 iMac to 2023 iMac Data Migration

Tags: imac, thunderbolt, migration

I'm migrating data from my 2010 27" iMac to a new 2023 24" iMac.  I purchased a Thunderbolt 2 to Thunderbolt 3 adapter and connected them and then launched the Migration Assistant.  The data is transferring via my home network instead of via Thuderbolt connection.  Ironically, the Migration dialog box says I can transfer data faster if I use a Thunderbolt connection.  Estimated time is 72 hours...I don't want to start over because my old iMac is creaky and takes hours just to boot up.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer...I will try that immediately

Answer (score 7):

Just connecting the two computers via Thunderbolt isn’t enough.  You have to create an IP network between the two.

- Each Mac needs to have an IP address assigned to the Thunderbolt connection.  Apple has an excellent guide called [Use IP over Thunderbolt to connect Mac computers](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/ip-thunderbolt-connect-mac-computers-mchld53dd2f5/mac)
- Move this connection up so it’s the highest priority in Network Settings/Preferences
- During migration, turn off your regular wireless or wired network to ensure all traffic goes through the TB connection.